# Put Facebook like XFBML button in line with Pinterest button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, styling, pinterest

I know similar questions have been aske before but I'm new at this and can't make sense of it. I'm fairly sure its a straightforward task but I can't do it.

I'm using a CMS on which I cannot access the css template currently.

All I want is to add a Pinterest button and facebook like button to my individual product pages using the html source code editor in a nice neat row. At the moment they display one below the other.

These are the codes:

```
<a data-pin-config="above" href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" data-pin-do="buttonBookmark">
  <img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png" />
</a>

<fb:like send="true" layout="button_count" width="100" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

How to write the correct styling code to achieve this?